# How to enforce a limit for each of my cases

Tags: mysql

Here is my query below

```
$sql="SELECT sum(`total`) as `total`, `a`, `type`
 FROM `table`
 GROUP BY `a`, `type`
ORDER BY `type`, 
          CASE WHEN `type`='type1' THEN `a` END ASC, 
          CASE WHEN `type`='type2' THEN `a` END DESC  LIMIT 15
```

Which works how I expect. But I would like 15 of type1 and 15 of type2. Instead I get eg 5 of type 1 and 10 of type 2, even though there is more than 15 of each of type1 and type2.

I want this accomplished if possible all within a single select, not with multiple selects. This is due to the data set rapidly changing.

Comment: I don’t see a way of getting that with a single SELECT statement. A UNION of two SELECTs will behave as a “single” one from the view of the application though.

Comment: What is `a`? Is it some key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `union all` is probably the easiest way to get what you want:

```
(SELECT sum(`total`) as `total`, `a`, `type`
 FROM `table`
 WHERE `type`= 'type1'
 GROUP BY `a`
 ORDER BY `a` desc
 LIMIT 15
) union all
(SELECT sum(`total`) as `total`, `a`, `type`
 FROM `table`
 WHERE `type`= 'type2'
 GROUP BY `a`
 ORDER BY `a` desc
 LIMIT 15
)
order by `type`, `a` desc;
```

Comment: Do you know if those two selects happen all in one go? For example, after that first select is done, imagine an insert happens into table of type2 before the second select starts, that would be bad for me if that second select then picked up that newly inserted row

Comment: @user1796995 . . . This is a single SQL query, so you are asking about the locking semantics of MySQL in inserts and updates.  This could be an issue.  But is would also be an issue with row-level/page-level locks on any query.  If this is an issue, you need to investigate different isolation levels.